# Datatable fnFilter not working, returns error

Tags: jquery, datatable

```
var oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable();
```

After i create the datatable, i should be able to use functions like `oTable.fnFilter()` for example. Instead i am getting a `TypeError: c is undefined error`.

I tried `console.log(oTable);` and it returns the jQuery object of the element (i think it supposed to return object that has datatable functions, not a jquery element).

Datatable itself works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to fix this issue, but no idea what caused it.

`oTable.fnFilter('some_val');` - caused the error and stopped all code below it.

added try catch blocks and the code below is no longer interrupted:

```
try {
  oTable.fnFilter('some_val');
} catch (e) {

}
```